# Different hostname / prompt is shown after logging in as root

Tags: bash, root, prompt

```
[mayur@centos ~]$ su
Password:
[root@centos mayur]#
```

I want it to be "centos" only. How to do it?

Comment: Check root's PS1. It probably encodes the hostname and the pwd.

Comment: It's not clear what you desired result is.

Comment: It is
[\u@\h \W]\$

Comment: @ jordanm I want the hostname as centos which is before being root user. After logging as root I want it to be same not centos mayur

Comment: It's not the *hostname* that's changing, it's the representation of the PWD (from `~` when `mayur` is your own home directory, to `mayur` when you change from user to root, where `~` would refer to root's home dir). If you want to change to root's home directory at the same time as logging in, then use `su -` or `su -l`.

Comment: @steeldriver  ~ would refer to root's home directory or mayur would refer it ? and is it possible to make it disappear or it's gonna be there ?

Comment: @Rui re: your title edit, it's tempting to guide/edit the question towards an answer, given what *we* know, but it's also nice to leave some keywords intact so that future searchers/searches can pick up similar misunderstandings, and then let the Answers correct the understanding. Just my 2 cents!

Comment: The `\W` in the PS1 refers to the trailing part of the current directory. The mayur user started off in their home directory, which bash simplified to `~`. When you `su`d (and not `su -`) to root, you were left in ~mayur, which is *not* root's home directory, so that's why you see 'mayur' there. Try doing `cd` as root afterwards.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Doing cd works. Thanks. But I guess I've to do it everytime.

Comment: It sounds like having the \W is distracting to you. Do you like seeing your current directory as the 'mayur' user, and just want to remove it from the root prompt?

Comment: I just want to remove it from prompt. It looks long prompt name.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment string, it sounds like you don't want to see the `\W` directory element in the `PS1` prompt string (explained here in [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)).

For your user (mayur) and/or root accounts, edit their .profile or .bashrc (wherever you found the PS1 setting already), and simply remove the `\W` portion of it, to make it something like:

```
PS1='[\u@\h]\$ '
```

You may eventually find that having the `\W` is helpful or useful, but at least now you know that your hostname is not really changing -- it's just your shell's prompt trying to be helpful.

As steeldriver also pointed out in the comments, you can avoid seeing this (exact) misleading prompt string by using `su -` instead of just `su`; this has (one) effect of changing your current directory to the target (root) user's home directory, so instead of

```
[root@centos mayur]#
```

you'd see:

```
[root@centos ~]#
```

Comment: Very welcome; happy we could reach an understanding. If this solves your problem, don't forget to use the checkmark to the left.